# Phonegap Android: reading a file and saving to localstorage

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova

Morning.

I am using the following code (Phonegap 2.9) to create/read a file on Android device.

```
function gotFS(fileSystem) {
            //alert('first try');
            savedFS = fileSystem;
            fileSystem.root.getFile("dp-locations.json", null, gotFileEntry2, fail);
        }

        function gotFS2(fileSystem) {
            //alert('try again');
            fileSystem.root.getFile("dp-locations.json", {create: true}, gotFileEntry, fail);
        }

        function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
            //alert('call writer');
            fileEntry.createWriter(gotFileWriter, fail);
        }

         function gotFileEntry2(fileEntry) {
            alert('fileentry2');
            //fileEntry.createWriter(gotFileWriter, fail);
            fileEntry.file(gotFile, failRead);
        }

        function gotFile(file){
        alert('gotfile');
            readAsText(file);
        }

        function readAsText(file) {
            alert('here I am');
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
                alert("Read as text");
                alert("rat2: "+evt.target.result);
            };

            reader.readAsText(file);
            reader.onload = function(evt){
                alert(reader.result);
            };
            }

        function failRead(evt) {
            alert("112: "+evt.target.error.code);
        }

        function gotFileWriter(writer) {
            writer.onwrite = function(evt) {
                //console.log("write success");
            };
            //writer.write('{"routes": {}}');//start writing to JSON file
            var routes = new Array();
            var test = new Object({"locations":[{"name":"first","values":["cw11 1gb","po45 5wd","ta6 3eq"]},{"name":"second","values":["cw7 2yg","po4 8ej","ta9 3zd"]}]});
            routes.push(test);
            writer.write(routes);//start writing to JSON file
            gotFileEntry2(fileEntry);            
        }

        function fail(error) {
            //console.log(error.code);
            if(error.code == 1){
                alert('not found');
                gotFS2(savedFS);
            }
            alert(error.code);
        }
```

My problem is that the script is creating the file (if it needs to), but, when the file aready exists, it doesn't seem to read it.

Function gotFile is called, but function readAsText does not seem to do as required.
I want the file contents to be added to localStorage.

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you try to remove reader.onload or to move it before reader.readAsText?

Comment: @Regent Yes, I tried both of those. No effect.

Comment: Does problem appear when you call "gotFileEntry2" from "gotFileWriter" (which, i think, should be called in writer.onwrite), or when you call "gotFS" again?

Comment: @Regent problem occurs in both scenarios

Comment: Using your code, i was able to write to file and to read it (read after app restart, all in emulator). The only problem i got was with "gotFileEntry2(fileEntry)" - because fileEntry is not defined there. I don't think it can impact reading after app restart, but the only thing i can suggest now to fix "gotFileEntry2(fileEntry)" line

Comment: @Regent gotFS2(fileSystem) works for me. It creates and writes to the file. It's reading the file on app restart that doesn't seem to work for me

Comment: Yes, i understand that, and your code (which reads file) looks good (as almost exact copy from docs) and also works for me, so i haven't got idea what is wrong with it. Maybe you should try to test on another device... Or, first of all, in emulator